# For what values of a when 2x – 3 = y and ax + y = 2 intersects? When they don’t intersect, what are the lines doing?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

So I have this question on my revision sheet for an upcoming test on simulataneous equations and linear relations. We haven’t learnt anything about this in class, so my attempt was pretty pitiful. I basically rearranged the first equation, 2x-3=y into 2x-y=3, to mirror the standard form of ax+y=2. But I have no idea what to do after this step.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Perhaps a better mirror form of $ax+y=2$ would be $-2x+y=-3$, though you might find this first part easier with the pair $y=2x-3$ and $y=-ax+2$

Answer (score 1):

Find slopes of your lines. If slopes are equal they do not intersect unless they are identical.

If slopes are different, they intersect.

Since one of your  slopes is in terms of $a$  you can find the values of $a$ for which lines intersect.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I transposed both equations into y=mx+c form, and I got  y= 2x-3 and y=-ax+2. However, I’m not sure what you mean by being able to find all the values of a which the lines intersect. Wouldn’t it mean that every value that isn’t -2 is a value of a? , as Cartesian planes are infinite so every line has an ability to intersect with the line y=2x-3?

Comment: You are right. There is only one value  of $a$ which makes  the lines parallel.